# How to validate a radio button group SimpleSchema

Tags: meteor

For example I have 4 radio buttons and only 1 button must be checked.

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="Programming"> Programming
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="Design"> Design
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="Finance"> Finance
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="Finance"> Other Category
</label>
```

Also I use Simple Schema to validate values, but in documentation I cant find how to validate radio buttons, maybe anyone can help me ?

Or I must do this whithout Simple Schema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You validate the value, like you would with a regular input box. The difference, is that you have to validate the value of the checked radio button.

So for example you have this on your HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="foobar" class="fetch_value" value="foo" checked> Foo<br>
<input type="radio" name="foobar" class="fetch_value" value="bar"> Bar<br>
```

And you have this on your js:

```
var fetched_values = document.getElementsByClassName("fetch_value");
for (var i=0; i< fetched_values.length; i++) {
    if (fetched_values[i].checked == true) {
        validate ("field_name", fetched_values[i].value);
    }
}

(...)

function validate (id, value) { 
    //Schemas.mySchema is the Schema name & myContext is a context of your choice
    var SchemaLink = Schemas.mySchema.namedContext("myContext");
    temp_obj = {};
    temp_obj[id] = value;
    var isValid = SchemaLink.validateOne(temp_obj, id);
    if (!isValid) {
        // invalidKeys is an array, even if you validate just one object
        var error = SchemaLink.invalidKeys();
        alert (Schema_link.keyErrorMessage(error[0].name) );
    }
}
```

This should do validation client-side, to do it server-side, you could use very similar code before the insert code (or use Collection2 package, and it'll validate every insert/update using SimpleSchema)

Comment: $("input[name=name]:checked").val(), - this faster , but what for Simple Schema, how to validate in it

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of a single validation.

Comment: a lot of code but helpful, but what if I use this 1)
 
$("input[name=name]:checked").val(), 2) simple js validation `if then else` ,?

Comment: Not sure I follow you. You can validate any number of ways. validate() and validateOne() use SimpleSchema own methods, but they mention you can also use check() or Match.test() if you want to use JS. There are a couple of example on the [GitHub doc](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#validation-options)

Comment: sorry, try to expaline, for example I have form with a lot of input, and if one of input is wrong or more how to show it good (UI) on the client not like ALERT, because simple schema return msg with string type 
but how to tie each error for each input in form OR it's very hard and I must use simple JS to validate form and show errors  
more pleasant for customers

Comment: You can for example, put every error message in a Session variable, and show it on HTML somewhere. 
The way I did it was using a unique ID on each input. The ID is sent to the validation, and when the validation fails then it searches for that ID, adds the "error" class to the input, and shows the error in a bootstrap popup over the input, but there are numerous ways to do it.